# How to query using ISODate in PyMongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, pymongo, isodate

Long story short, I'm trying to do [this](https://www.w3resource.com/mongodb-exercises/mongodb-exercise-22.php) query in PyMongo for the last two days. Please help.

```
for x in restaurants.find( 
            {"grades":
             {"$elemMatch":
              {'date': dateutil.parser.parse("2014-08-11T00:00:00Z"),
               'grade':'A',
               'score':11
              }}},
{"name":1,
 "grades.grade":1,
 "grades.score":1,
 "grades.date":1
}):
print(x)
```

Edit: [Here](https://www.w3resource.com/mongodb-exercises/restaurants.zip)'s the database. It's Structure:
[image]

I'm trying to write a query to find the restaurant Id, name, and grades for those restaurants which achieved a grade of "A" and scored 11 on an ISODate "2014-08-11T00:00:00Z" among many of survey dates.

I'm starting to think there's something wrong with either the date I'm entering or the database. Also, as you can see in the fourth line of code I AM using a time object. Please try querying yourself. Its not working.

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: How to do the query correctly? I'm not getting any result. Not even an error. When I remove " 'date': dateutil.parser.parse("2014-08-11T00:00:00Z"), ", it works but I need to put the dates too.

Comment: You should include essential part of the link that you provided and create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Consider updating your question with the specific error/behaviour with your current attempt too.

Answer (score 0):

`pymongo` doesn't use "ISODate", it's a Mongo type, you should just use `datetime` to create a time object, like so:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

parsed_date = datetime.strptime("2014-08-11T00:00:00Z", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
timezone = pytz.timezone("UTC")
with_timezone = timezone.localize(parsed_date)

for x in restaurants.find(
        {
            "grades":
                {
                    "$elemMatch": {
                        'date': with_timezone,
                        'grade': 'A',
                        'score': 11
                    }
                }
        },
        {
            "name": 1,
            "grades.grade": 1,
            "grades.score": 1,
            "grades.date": 1
        }):
    print(x)
```

Comment: 'x' is not defined. Also, did you tried yourself? There might be something wrong with the database.

Comment: the "for" loop is your code, i just copied it.

Comment: Before "for loop", x in:
with_timezone = timezone.localize(x)

Also, I am using a time object:
dateutil.parser.parse("2014-08-11T00:00:00Z")

Comment: ah oops, that's mb, that `x` is suppose to be `parsed_date`, i'll fix that.